# Integrating react native in existing iOS & android project without modifying existing directory structure

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

Currently, we have separate native iOS & native android repos. Say A & B respectively

I am trying to integrate react native in A & B.

I am referring:- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html

Above tutorial is forcing me to create new directory structure with iOS,android & JS folder inside main project. Thus, allowing me to have only 1 repo (see below)

[image]

My requirement is:
1)I don't want to hamper directory structure of existing android & iOS repos
2)Can we have separate JS repo "C" ?

See below

[image]

Does anyone have the same scenario? How to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you achieve this finally?

Answer (score 2):

This is very possible. We currently use a similar scenario in production. We have an Android repo A and an iOS repo B. 
We created a separate React Native repo C.
A depends on C through a maven dependency.
B depends on C through a cocoapod dependency.

The tricky part is to specify the path when building your dependencies. For example in iOS the official docs state this in the podfile:

> pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [

In our case it is something like

> pod 'React', :path => '/../YourReactNativeApp/node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [

And then when you checkout your React Native repo, in our case, we must make sure that the folder checked out is adjacent to our our iOS project folder.

Comment: Unable to use ' use_native_modules!' if we seperate the project folders. Is there any update for this?